# Peewee Native compression instead of CompressedField

Tags: peewee

I am using peewee and I'd like to use compressed field in MariaDB. The table is created like this via SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
(
    field_name   BLOB COMPRESSED,
);
```

In peewee `CompressedField` is a wrapper around `BlobField`. Not all of my users accessing the database use peewee so I would like to use the built-in transparent compression of InnoDB in MariaDB. How do I tell peewee to create the field `field_name` with compression when using peewee's `create_tables()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very very easily add a custom field type. This is described in the docs:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-a-custom-field

This should be all you need:

```
class CompressedBlobField(BlobField):
    field_type = 'BLOB COMPRESSED'
```